# Google Tag Manager get dataset from clicked element

Tags: javascript, dataset, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get the data-action property from a  button.

I have multiple buttons, with different data-action's:

```
<button type="button" class="a-Button js-actionButton" data-action="search"><span class="a-Button-label">search</span></button>

<button type="button" class="a-Button js-actionButton" data-action="printen">print document</button>
```

I know I can get the value of a data-action by the following:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.js-actionButton');
el =  el.dataset.action
```

I need some help with returning the dataset.action in Google Tag Manager.

This is what I've tried:

```
return {{Click Element}}.dataset.action;

var el = document.querySelector({{Click Element}}.className);
return el.dataset.action;
```

Comment: One problem with that is that in your first example the click element will actually be the span, not the button with the data attribute. You'd either need to traverse upwards from the click element until you find an element with a dataset, or implement a custom click handler in a custom HTML tag that is attached to elements with the data-action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide us from a website URL? Create a javascript variable as below example. Does this sounds as a solution?

```
function(){
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('a-Button js-actionButton').innerHTML;
return el;
}
```